# How can my teams bot respond to comments that have been made on it's own thread?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am unaware of a method using botbuilder that allows a teams bot to reply to (non mention) comments on its own threads.

Here is the gist of the bots reply (it is the hello world example given at : https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-nodejs):

```
 var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function(session) {
        // Message might contain @mentions which we would like to strip off in the response
        var text = teams.TeamsMessage.getTextWithoutMentions(session.message);
        session.send('You said: %s', text);
    }).set('storage', inMemoryBotStorage);
```

I want the teams bot to reply to comments on threads it is involved in, (initiated with an original mentioned comment). I do not know how to accomplish this (or if it is possible with botbuilder-teams)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [Proactive Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#creating-a-channel-conversation) documentation. Here is [Node sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/blob/master/src/dialogs/examples/teams/ProactiveMsgToChannelDialog.ts) sample for proactive message to channel.

Here is code snippet to start reply chain:

```
    var message = new teams.TeamsMessage(session).text("This is start message.");
    connector.startReplyChain(serviceUrl, channelId, message, function (err, address) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            session.endDialog('There is some error');
        }
        else {
            console.log(address);
            var msg = new teams.TeamsMessage(session)
            .text('This is reply to your message.')
            .address(address);
            session.send(msg);
            session.endDialog();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this with botbuilder?